# <li> becomes &lt;li&gt; when adding to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a script where i write a new project to my database.
In this script i have a textarea element with name="omschrijving".
In this textarea the user can specify < li> elements which i have styled with css.

The problem is, that when i enter: <li>hello</li> becomes: & lt;li>hello&lt ;/li> in my database.

I use a mediumtext type column to store the value of the textarea in.

Code of my form:

```
<form action="nieuwproject.php?action=toevoegen" method="post">

                            <fieldset class=""> <!-- Set class to "column-left" or "column-right" on fieldsets to divide the form into columns -->



                                <p>
                                    <label>Naam</label>
                                    <input class="text-input medium-input datepicker" type="text" id="medium-input" name="naam" />
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <label>Categorie</label>
                                    <select name="categorie" class="text-input medium-input">
                                       <?php $oObj->getCategorieDropdown(); ?> 
                                    </select>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <label>Opdrachtgever</label>
                                    <input class="text-input medium-input datepicker" type="text" id="medium-input" name="opdrachtgever" />
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <label>Omschrijving</label>
                                    <textarea class="text-input textarea wysiwyg" id="textarea" name="omschrijving" cols="79" rows="15"></textarea>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <label>Werkzaamheden</label>
                                    <textarea class="text-input textarea wysiwyg" id="textarea" name="werkzaamheden" cols="79" rows="15"></textarea>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                                </p>

                            </fieldset>

                            <div class="clear"></div><!-- End .clear -->

                        </form>
```

Code of my Insert script:

```
function addProject() {
    $this->sQuery = "INSERT INTO projecten (naam,opdrachtgever,omschrijving,werkzaamheden,categorie) 
        VALUES ('" . $_POST['naam'] . "','" . $_POST['opdrachtgever'] . "','" . $_POST['omschrijving'] . "','" . $_POST['werkzaamheden'] . "','" . $_POST['categorie'] . "')";
    $this->rResult = mysql_query($this->sQuery);
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
I am aware this script is candy to hackers, so theres no need to point that out.

With kind regards,

Michael

Comment: what happens if you use html_entity_decode ($_POST['werkzaamheden']) also what wysiwyg editor are you using for your text areas as this can sometimes alter your tags

Comment: I am using this WYSIWYG editor:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jWYSIWYG

EDIT:
Its outdated i just noticed. I'll just upgrade to CKEditor then :)

Comment: silly question: are you pasting the lis straight into the wysiwyg as code or are you using the wysiwyg functionality to make lis?

Comment: i was typing it myself. The jQuery WYSIWYG does not have the option for LI elements, so i was forced to type.
Upgrading to CKEditor would be a better option i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure.
just find the place in your code which does `htmlspecialchars/htmlentities` on the data intended for database and get rid of it.

**I can assure you that database never adds no symbols by it's own will.**
Every symbol that is altered/added to your data is a result of some PHP code.

Note that your query is improperly formatted.
You have to format it, either by formatting every literal separately, or by using prepared statements.
It is irrelevant to your `li&gt` problem, but it's relevant to your application errors and vulnerability

Comment: Im aware of that, but the funny thing is that i have removed every single htmlspecialchars/entities already but it still does what it does.

Comment: Oh, i fixed the problem already!
It was caused by my WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

MySQL won't sanitize your html like this, as far as I know, so something in your code is passing your `$_POST['omschrijving']` through `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`. Either of these functions would produce the out put that your are seeing in your database.

Edit:

Just saw your comment that it was your WYSIWYG editor. Good catch!